# I do have one dynamic dropdownlist and textbox addition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a DropDownList and Textbox on my page.

The DropDownList bringing data from database dynamically.

I want that when I choose any item from dropdownlist, it should appear inside the textbox immediately.

How to do it???

Comment: @relentless What does it mean???

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what code you have now; what code produces the DropDownList, what Produces the TextBox, your "choose" event handler (if any) etc etc. This has way too little information to give any decent answer.

Comment: @Nenotlep Thanks for concern......it is done now!!

Comment: @VipinSaini The thing is, Stackoverflow questions are not just for you, people might very well use this question to solve their own problem and so when they find this in it's current state, it is very unclear what you are asking. To make a genuine contribution to the collective Q&A knowledge base that is StackOverflow, I think that maintaining asked questions and making them useful to others even after you have solved your specific issue is a valuable thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution... by using javascript

```
<select id="select" onchange="return getValue();">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
{
var e = document.getElementById("select");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("textbox").value = str;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not complete. You need to add an event listener listening to changes to the select menu.

Comment: @Theox ohhh yeah... I just forgot that.. Let me update my answer.. thanks

Comment: @Nishant Solanki ..... Thanks for concern, it is done now

Comment: @VipinSaini if you find my answer useful please select it as correct and +1 it... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery way

**HTML CODE:**

```
  <select id="select" name="ddlb">
   <option value="1" selected='selected'>option 1</option>
   <option value="2">option 2</option>
   <option value="3">option 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="textbox" id="txt">
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
  $('#select').on('change', function () {
     $('#txt').val($('#select option:selected').val());
  });
  $('#txt').val($('#select option:selected').val());
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PfBFS/2/

Happy Coding :)